# IndexError: Python

Tags: python

In the code from below, I wanted to insert some data in a matrix and I was surprised by **IndexError**.
I can't understand why the error is here, it seems that everything is wright.

```
matrix=[[]]
n=int(input("number of lines and columns n= "))
for i in range(n):
   for j in range(n):
    x=int(input())
    matrix[i].insert(j,x)
    print(i,j)
```

**EDIT:**

I understand that my problem had nothing to do with what I thought initially. The mistake was that I wanted to insert *x* in a list that didn't exist in my *matrix* variable. The solution is just to append a new list in the first loop, and after that to add desired elements.

Comment: `m` has a length of 1. When you try to access its 2nd element, you get an IndexError.

Comment: Maybe you want/need to create a new sublist with each iteration of the outer loop - like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/52542948/2823755

Comment: `m[0]` grows with each call to `insert`; `m` does not.

Comment: Thanks jwebb, that's what I wanted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`m` is a `list of lists` Which means that you first need to append a list, and then you can append items to each list.

Just changed your code a bit to do that. Once in every repetition of the outer loop, I append an empty list.

```
m=[[]]
n=6
for i in range(n):
    m.append([])
    for j in range(n):
        x=5
        m[i].insert(j,x)
        print(i,j)
```

Try here:
https://ideone.com/bSGIiD

That should solve your problem.